# Android emulation

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk, android-emulator

Can someone direct me to an Android emulator outside of Android Studio, that's open source and for Ubuntu, not Wine. I used to use Android SDK but don't like the Studio update and am now using a paid for application that I'm not thrilled with.